# mailitem.Save The operation cannot be completed because the objct has been deleted

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to make a copy of a mailitem, move the copy to a different location and add a custom item property to it. But after I add the custom property, the item wont save and crash with the error mentionned above.

Here's my code, help me figure this out please!

```
Dim objCopiedItem, objControlItem
Set objCopiedItem = item.Copy
Call objCopiedItem.Move(objPSTFolder)

Dim property1 : Set property1 = GetMigrationProperty(objCopiedItem.ItemProperties)
  if property1 is nothing Then
     Set property1 = objCopiedItem.ItemProperties.Add("Migration ID", 1)
     property1.Value = item.EntryID
     objCopiedItem.Save
 else
   property1.Value = item.EntryID
   objCopiedItem.Save
 End If
```

The error occurs at objCopiedItem.Save, the operation works without problems if I add the properties to the original item and then copy/move and the new item, then delete the property on the original item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move is a function that returns the new item, not a sub:

```
Set objCopiedItem = item.Move(objPSTFolder)
```